# import, exportがエラーになる

Tags: javascript, html

import, exportを使用したいのですが、エラーになってしまいます。

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

どこに問題があるのでしょうか？

**const.js**

```
export const DATA = {
    test: "qqq"
};
```

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="text"></div>

        <script src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            import DATA from "../const";
            $("#text").text(DATA.test)
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

未だ、一部のブラウザでしか動かない実験的（？）機能ではありますが、以下3点の修正でChromeなどでは動くと思います。

- `import` を使うスクリプトの `<script>` タグに `type="module"` を指定する
- デフォルトエクスポートされていないメンバーを `import` する際はメンバー名を `{ }` で囲う
- モジュールファイルの拡張子は省略しない

```html
<script type="module">
import {DATA} from "./const.js"
```

Comment: まだ公式ではない手法なのですね。
サーバー側で実行したかったのですが、サーバー搭載のブラウザが対応していなかったので実装自体は見送りにいたしましたが、ありがとうございました！